# How to find cotangent of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, trigonometric-series

I am having really small problem but don't know why Google search is not yielding fruitful results.

if

```
cotangent(x) = 1/tangent(x)
```

then how to find

```
cotangent(x+iy)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is given in Abramowitz/Stegun formula 4.3.58 or at http://dlmf.nist.gov/4.21.E40
$$\cot z = \cot(x + iy) = \frac{\sin 2x - i \sinh 2y}{\cosh 2
y - \cos 2x}$$

Comment: cot(2+3i) = -0.0037-0.9968i answer is calculated using MATLAB R2015a but by using this formula answer coming out is -0.0037518+3.0860i

Comment: What do you mean with your comment? In fact you have
$$\frac{\sin 4}{\cosh 6 - \cos 4} \approx -0.003739710,\quad -\frac{\sinh 6}{\cosh 6 - \cos 4} \approx -0.9967577966$$ What formula did you use?

Comment: The one you provided

Comment: Since the values shown above  are the same as MATLAB,  you have a problem somewhere else.

Comment: I am sorry for misunderstanding just typed wrong formula by accident in MATLAB. I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$\cot(A+B)=\dfrac{\cot A\cot B-1}{\cot B+\cot A}$$

Now $\cot(iy)=\dfrac{\cos(iy)}{\sin(iy)}=\dfrac{\cosh(y)}{i\sinh(y)}$

Comment: Where is x in cot(iy)?

Comment: @KamilMahmood, You can keep $\cot(x)$ as is

Comment: cot(2+3i) = -0.0037-0.9968i answer is calculated using MATLAB R2015a but by using this formula answer coming out is -0.4577+1.0050i

Comment: @KamilMahmood, Have you understood my method?

Comment: I think I have not understood your method correctly.

Comment: @KamilMahmood: He's just saying to use $A=x$ and $B=iy$, so $A+B=x +iy$. Then his hint gives you a way to simplify $\cot B$, i.e., $\cot iy$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You can always express any trig function of a complex argument in terms of trig/hyperbolic functions of a real argument using the basic facts that
$$\sin it =i\sinh t$$
$$\cos it =\cosh t$$
Note that these are completely analogous to the formulas
$$\sin -t =-\sin t$$
$$\cos -t =\cos t$$

These, along with the normal sum formulas for sine and cosine, let you simplify any trig function of a complex number (because the other trig functions are expressable in terms of sine and cosine).